# Does implementing IServiceBehavior affect ServiceBehavior attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, attributes, servicebehavior

I have a WCF service. I need to implement IServiceBehavior in my class that implements ServiceContract. I have some some attributes on that class that specify service behavior. I wanted to ask if after implementing IServiceBehavior behaviors specified in attributes still apply.

Basically does

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, 
                 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
...
}
```

mean same thing as

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, 
                 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class MyService : IMyService, IServiceBehavior
{
...
}
```

By the same I mean that I still have `ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)`.

My implementation of IServiceBehavior is as follows:

```
void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, 
                          ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, 
                          Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, 
                          BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
{            
}

void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, 
                           ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
{
    IErrorHandler handler = new ErrorHandler();
    foreach (ChannelDispatcher dispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
    {
        dispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(handler);
    }
}

void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
{            
}
```

I just want to implement central error handling, I don't want to change service behavior in any other way.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the behavior in the ServiceBehaviorAttribute still applies; your IServiceBehavior just provides a way for you to provide further customization of the runtime.